# Mysql union remove zero

Tags: mysql

I would like to merge two tables,but it removes zero when i used union all in stroeprocedure in mysql.

Two tables as the following:

```
TBL1:

ID VAL1 VAL2
2    3    3
3    3    0

TBL2 

ID VAL1 VAL2
3   0   3
4   0   4

Select ID,VAL1,VAL2 FROM TBL1
UNION ALL
Select ID,VAL2,VAL2 FROM TBL2;

ERROR RESULT:
   ID VAL1 VAL2
    2    3   3
    3    3    
    3        3
    4        4

RIGHT RESULT:
   ID VAL1 VAL2
    2    3   3
    3    3   0
    3    0   3
    4    0   4
```

How to keep Zero value when we use union all ?

Regards,

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb003/1). Also there is a little issue (you have selected Val2 twice from the second table) but it is not related to your issue.

Comment: Your query works correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34126/1 Search for the error somewhere else

Comment: This problem can't be reproduced with the given information. Are you running this query directly in MySQL or through some programming language? Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     Select ID,IF(VAL1 =0, 0,val1) val1,VAL2 FROM TBL1
    UNION ALL
   Select ID,IF(VAL1 =0, 0,val1) val1,VAL2 FROM TBL2;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0845/1)

if same thing is with you VAL2 then use also `IF(VAL2 =0, 0,val2) val2` for val2

your query looks right look demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0845/2

Comment: Your query produces the same result without IF: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0845/2

Comment: Hello is empty value in table.

Comment: something is wrong with your code , the query is good as you see demo.

Comment: Hello is empty string in table. it hasn't 0 value in table.

Comment: something is wrong with your code , the query is good as you see demo.